# How to stop loading website if it's trying to escape from a frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, framebusting

So I know that there are many websites out there that try to break from frames (frame-busting) and then there is this whole cyclic "busting frame busters" and "busting frame buster busters" etc.  Is there a way to anticipate whether a website will try to break out of your frame?  I want my program to try to load the site into a frame, and if it tries to break out, just abandon the attempt and stop loading the frame.  This is what I tried before:

```
<iframe id="framed_source" src = "<%= @excerpt.url %>"></iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if ( top === self )
    {
        $(".framed_source").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Unfortunately, even with removing the iframe it still redirects to the original site?  How can I just remove the frame and abandon the attempt to load their website at all so no redirecting occurs?

Comment: how can top ever === to self ?

Comment: @Val If the current window (`self`) is the outermost window (`top`).

Answer (score 0):

here is an example

```
<div id="pcontent"></div> <!-- Page 1 html -->
<script>
   setInterval(function(){//set interval
       if(!$('iframe').contents().find('#icontent').length)//check if div exists on iframe
          window.location.href= 'blbla.com';//if so redirect
    },100);//end interval
</script>
<iframe> <!-- This is your iframe below is the javascript code should go to page2.html -->
   <div id="icontent"></div>
   <script>
     setInterval(function(){
      if(!top.getElementById('pcontent').length)//check if the div exists on top most window
      window.location.href= 'blbla.com';
     },100);
   </script>
</iframe>
```

Now: Inside the iframe is what the iframe should have ... [illustration only]

You can also check for other things like, if contents don't have width, height, inner text and html don't match etc...

Comment: Can you explain how this code is supposed to work?  I'm having a little trouble following it

Comment: I ran this code and it just renders an empty iframe and an empty page -- I don't understand what it signifies or how it answers my question about redirecting away before frame breakout.

Comment: the things inside the iframe should be where ever ur url points..., and I said its only for guide lines, it's a very complicated thing it can't be explained that easily ...

Comment: Can you try to explain it anyway?  I really don't feel comfortable using code I don't understand.

Comment: The above is the best way I can describe it, By I think you are trying to run b4 you can walk... Try some more simple stuff, how to deal with iframes then this.

Answer (score 0):

with this code the user will be prompted, and if he wants he can keep in your page...(I've not tried it)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload=function(e){
       $(".framed_source").remove();
       return 'Please keep here I will remove that buster iframe!';
    }
<script type="text/javascript">
```